# Get random n values from the range - Elixir

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Need to get random 2 values from the range 0..9.
I tried as,

```
iex(13)> Enum.take_random(Enum.to_list(0..9),2)
[3, 0]
iex(14)>
nil
iex(15)> Enum.take_random(Enum.to_list(0..9),2)
'\a\b'
```

Comment: `'\a\b' == [7, 8]`. Let me know if the linked answer doesn't answer your question.

Comment: Also, you can pass the range directly to `Enum.take_random`. Doing `Enum.to_list()` on it first is unnecessarily inefficient.

Comment: take_random will give only one value, but i need more than one random value

Comment: `take_random` returns as many values as you pass as the second argument. You've even posted a code snippet which shows this behavior. Are you expecting a different result than in the code snippet in the question?

Comment: but take_random need list as one input , i need to convert my range to input right?

Comment: `take_random` takes any `Enumerable` as input and a range is an `Enumerable`. You can pass the range as it is. `Enum.take_random(1..10, 2)` works.

Comment: `Enum.take_random(1..10, 2) |> to_charlist` will always work :)